# Replay image transformation

Tags: graphics, imagemagick, gimp

I regularly need to merge 3 or more images into one, where one image is the base and the other images are added as overlays and are transformed to fit the base image using the cage transform tool in gimp.

That worked great so far, but now for big images (> 20k x 20k pixels) editing is very slow even with okayish CPU (Ryzen 5 3600) and big RAM (42GB) - sometimes gimp even crashes.

Is there maybe a possibility to do the manual editing on a smaller version of the images and the "replay" the transformation on the real size images on a fast server or somewhere else?

Comment: Have you tried GIMP scripting?

Comment: Add a couple of lines of IM code that create representative examples of what your images are like even if only a white rectangle on a red background, then we can see what the processing looks like and how your command looks.